# How to get the modules included in a class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, module, subclass

How can I get an array of modules included in a class, excluding those that slipped in through inheritance?

Notice that `ancestors`, `<=>`, `included_modules` will not work because their results do not distinguish modules that are included from modules that are prepended in a superclass. In other words, they cannot distinguish the following two cases:

- `M` is prepended to the superclass of `B`

  ```
  class A; end
  class B < A; end
  module M; end
  A.prepend M

  B.ancestors # => [B, M, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  B <=> M # => -1
  B.included_modules # => [M, Kernel]
  ```
- `M` is included in `B`

  ```
  class A; end
  class B < A; end
  module M; end
  B.include M

  B.ancestors # => [B, M, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  B <=> M # => -1
  B.included_modules # => [M, Kernel]
  ```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Creating a class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mixed_in  = B.included_modules[0...-B.superclass.included_modules.size]
prepended = B.ancestors.take_while { |ancestor| ancestor != B }
included  = mixed_in - prepended
```

Comment: A problem with `included_modules` is that, unlike `ancestors`, it does not distinguish prepended modules from included modules. So, from the result of your code, I cannot tell if the modules were prepended to or included in `B`.

Comment: I think you mean `ancestor != B`, not `ancestor = !B`.

Comment: When both `A.prepend M` and `B.include M`, `mixed_in  == prepended ==  []`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That depends on the order. If `A.prepend M` happens first, then `B.include M` has no effect (`M` will actually not be included in `B`). If the order is the other way around, then `M` will appear twice in `included_modules` of `B` and once in `B.superclass.included_modules.