# How to detect my anonymous modules in ancestors of some class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

During long run I [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) foreign classes with my anonymous modules (that are being created on the fly.)

At some point, given an instance of arbitrary class, I need to list *my anonymous modules*, `prepended` to it. Unfortunately, `Module#new`, unlike `Class#new`, does not accept a `parent` parameter (in other words, they cannot all have a same common dummy parent, that I could use to *sieve* my modules out of all `ancestors`.)

I could define a specific `my_litmus_dummy_method` on each of my anonymous modules and check for it while `ancestors.select`, but this is ugly.

I could `include DummyLitmusModule` in each of my anonymous modules and check for it being an ancestor while `ancestors.select`, but this is ugly either.

So, my question is: **is there any elegant way to *mark* my anonymous modules so that later on I could easily sieve them out of all modules list?**

---

**UPD** Code example

```
def patch_class klazz
  klazz.send :prepend, Module.new { define_method(:my_method) {} }
end

...

# load list of classes from somewhere and patch them
classes = my_parse_yaml('config.yml')
classes.each do |c|
  patch_class c
end

...

# somewhere in other place
instance.patches # ⇐ I want to implement this
```

At this point I need^W want to know, what methods were patched. I kinda reimplement [`alias_method_chain`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain) from Rails and I want to report the “usages” to my interface user.

Comment: Not very clear to me (especially about the `my_litmus...` method or `DummyLitmusModule`). Is your point that (i) you want to distinguish prepended modues from included ones, and (ii) you only care about the anonymous ones, not the named ones?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484006) is related.

Comment: Why not give your anonymous module a name?

Comment: @sawa At some point I have an instance of arbitrary class. My goal is to select all my specific anonymous modules out of it’s ancestors.

Comment: @Aetherus because basically there could be dozens of these modules (different one from other) and enumerating them like `MyModule_#{autoinc}` and then regexping names looks as a hack to me as well.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think if you need to refer to something (not just a module), you have to hold its ID. An ID could be the name of a variable whose value is invariable, a constant name, a method which always return that thing, etc. If there's no such ID, I'm afraid you have no way to find it.

Comment: @Aetherus yes, it seems to be that way. I ended up with including private dummy module, which looks like a most error-prone way (unless some weirdo decided to include it into her modules as well :).

Comment: You could show some example code? I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Stefan Updated. Shed I some light? I admit that I might do everything wrong, and I finally succeeded with including dummy module into my `Module.new` blocks, but anyway I still wonder whether it’s possible to retrieve this metainfo directly from MRI.

Comment: @Stefan That is the question.

Answer (score 1):

What about patching [Module#prepend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend)?

```
class Module
  attr_reader :mods_prepended
  alias :old_prepend :prepend
  def prepend(*mods)
    @mods_prepended =|| {}
    (@mods_prepended[self] =|| []).concat(mods)
  end
  old_prepend(*mods)
end

class C
  def patches
    Module.mods_prepended[self.class]
  end
end
```

Then the desired information is given by:

```
C.new.patches
```

Comment: I’ve been thinking about that. This looks fine by all means, but I am afraid of patching `Module#prepend` :) This is an irrational fear, that came from early 90s. Back then it became popular to `#define A B` in some C/C++ libraries to quickly achieve the desired result. I trust myself, but in production I am to keep Whales and Turtle intact.

Comment: Another glitch is that I am fine with `instance#patches` being time consuming, but I reject adding penalties to generic methods. Anyway, upvoted as it’s the best answer all over here. Not marked as correct because I still hope that there could be some magic we all are still missing.

Comment: Subclassing module sounds promising: even this `alias` crap would have gone away. Maybe that. I will give it a try in my tests, and report back, thanks, Cary!

Comment: Would subclassing `Module` or using `Refinements` allay your fears? (Response is above, and below.) :-)

Comment: Unfortunately no. `prepend` is called on foreign classes. `prepended` callback is static :( Anyway, I have to think more about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Store your anonymous modules somewhere and then you will be able to find them:

```
patches = [Module.new] # some other module
c = Class.new
m = Module.new
c.prepend m
patches << m

instance = c.new
used_patches = patches.select{|p| instance.is_a? p}
```

Comment: Yeah, global variables, love it.

Comment: @mudasobwa since any named class/module is in fact a global variable - this may not be so bad